# Google Webmaster Tools complains about missing robots.txt

Tags: google-search-console, robots.txt, googlebot

Nine days ago, I got a message Google Webmaster Tools:

> Over the last 24 hours, Googlebot encountered 1 errors while attempting to access your robots.txt.

Well, but I don't have a robots.txt on that site, because robots.txt is optional and I want the whole site to be crawled. So why do I get this error message?

Perhaps of interest: The Google Webmaster tools home page lists www.realitybuilder.com and realitybuilder.com. I don't know how that happened, but realitybuilder.com redirects to www.realitybuilder.com, so it should not be necessary to have it listed. I now deleted the entry for realitybuilder.com. Could that have caused the problem?

[image: Missing robots.txt error message]

Comment: Have you _ever_ had a robots.txt file on your site?

Comment: @w3d: I don't think so. For that site it wouldn't make sense anyhow. It's a one page web app.

Comment: One suspicion by me is that the entire site was indeed offline for some time, and Googlebot got a 500. Google could just provide more details, and I wouldn't need to ask here.

Comment: It is quite usual to have both `www.example.com` and `example.com` listed in GWT. You must have added both for both to be present. You say that `www.` is the main site (that is redirected to), however, your error appears to relate to the non-www version?

Comment: @w3d Yes, the error applies to the non-www version, as you can see in the screenshot.

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe it's because you have a redirect to a non-existent file? `example.com/robots.txt` redirects to `www.example.com/robots.txt` (404) - It could be useful to have a robots.txt file, even if it's empty, just to prevent 404's polluting your own logs?

Comment: @w3d Note that the redirect is not specific to robots.txt, it's for any path. Of course, adding `robots.txt` (and `humans.txt`) is a good idea, but 1. I am currently too lazy for that, 2. it should work without, and 3. I want to understand Google's error message.

Comment: Has this issue been resolved? I am encountering the same thing and would love to know how to fix it.

Comment: @user29946 I didn't get the message in months, despite *not* having changed anything. So it's still unclear what's going on.

Comment: If Googlebot rec'd a 500, as you state above in comments, (or anything other than a 404 or valid 200) on the 28 Jan 2013 then I would have said this was quite a probable cause of Google's error. Just to note, if a site is offline for planned maintenance, then it should return a 503 and preferably with a `Retry-After` response header.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why webmaster tools does this but I've had a similar problem with my site. When it was in development, I blocked it using the robots.txt file, then removed the block when it went live, but webmaster tools took a while to update itself.

What I'd recommend is to do a fetch as Googlebot and submit all pages, that should get Google looking at your site again quicker.

One last thing, your right robots.txt is optional but it might help the search engines understand better in you make a robots.txt file and set it to:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow:
```

Which is just like saying all pages are allowed.

Comment: Only, I highly doubt that I ever put a `robots.txt` on that site. And, in any case, I didn't update the site in many months.

Comment: I now did the fetch as Google. Please note that while your answer is helpful, I cannot mark it as accepted since it doesn't answer the *why*.

Comment: as to the why im not sure, reading over this question though i rember i asked somthing extremly similar a while back, have a look at this it may be helpful - http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/38099/google-webmaster-showing-warnings-blocked-by-robots-txt-but-its-not

Comment: Thanks, @sam, for pointing me to your question. There is a big difference, though: You get an error message because of an existing `robots.txt`, I get one because of a missing `robots.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

[This error](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2409682) occur when your robots.txt file exists but is unreachable. Your site should return 200 HTTP status if the file exists or 404 if it doesn't, otherwise you would face such message from google.

> Before Googlebot crawls your site, it accesses your robots.txt file to
>   determine if your site is blocking Google from crawling any pages or
>   URLs. If your robots.txt file exists but is unreachable (in other
>   words, if it doesn’t return a 200 or 404 HTTP status code), we’ll
>   postpone our crawl rather than risk crawling URLs that you do not want
>   crawled. When this happens, Googlebot will return to your site and
>   crawl it as soon as we can successfully access your robots.txt file.

Comment: It would be best to include a link to the source of that quote.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Done, thank you for your notice.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t have a robot.txt file and Googlebot encountered 1 error, then I think you have to define your robots.txt.

Robots.txt is a simple text file. If you want your entire website to be crawled, then you can define your robots.txt file as below.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

In this file `User-agent: *` means this section applies to all robots and the `Disallow:` tells the robot that it should visit all the pages on the site.

Upload your robots.txt file with this code and after few days see that Google webmaster tool shows any error or not.